# Split and Pivot a Data Frame

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, pivot, dataframe, pivot-table

I have a pandas data frame with the below values:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5], [2000, 2000, 2000, 5000, 2000, 5000, 2000, 5000, 2000, 5000], [0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 3], [233, 233, 96, 96, 53, 53, 29, 29, 24, 24], [251.109065, 251.109065, 300.141548, 412.916402, 291.836682, 394.260558, 327.351227, 478.924355, 371.598847, 574.811102], [18.858343, 18.858343, 67.874851, -127.405555, 58.692756, -148.001670, 95.252774, -63.949017, 136.983014, 26.888185]]).T


df1.columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6', 'col7']

df1 

   col1  col2  col3  col4  col5        col6        col7
0     2     1  2000     0   233  251.109065   18.858343
1     2     1  2000     3   233  251.109065   18.858343
2     2     2  2000     0    96  300.141548   67.874851
3     2     2  5000     3    96  412.916402 -127.405555
4     2     3  2000     0    53  291.836682   58.692756
5     2     3  5000     3    53  394.260558 -148.001670
6     2     4  2000     0    29  327.351227   95.252774
7     2     4  5000     3    29  478.924355  -63.949017
8     2     5  2000     0    24  371.598847  136.983014
9     2     5  5000     3    24  574.811102   26.888185
```

Now based on the combination of values from col1 and col2 I want to split col3 as two separate columns with values from col4. And based on this col6 and col7 also need to be split as two separate columns respectively. So my resulting dataframe need to be like this:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[2, 2, 2, 2, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000], [2000, 5000, 5000, 5000, 5000], [233, 96, 53, 29, 24], [251.109065, 300.141548, 291.836682, 327.351227, 371.598847], [251.109065, 412.916402, 394.260558, 478.924355, 574.811102], [18.858343, 67.874851, 58.692756, 95.252774, 136.983014], [18.858343, -127.405555, -148.00167, -63.949017, 26.888185]]).T


df2.columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3_0', 'col3_3', 'col5', 'col6_0', 'col6_3', 'col7_0', 'col7_3']

df2

   col1  col2  col3_0  col3_3  col5      col6_0      col6_3      col7_0      col7_3
0     2     1    2000    2000   233  251.109065  251.109065   18.858343   18.858343
1     2     2    2000    5000    96  300.141548  412.916402   67.874851 -127.405555
2     2     3    2000    5000    53  291.836682  394.260558   58.692756 -148.001670
3     2     4    2000    5000    29  327.351227  478.924355   95.252774  -63.949017
4     2     5    2000    5000    24  371.598847  574.811102  136.983014   26.888185
```

Note that '0' and '3' are values from col4 and this is used as suffix for the new columns : col3_0, col3_3col6_0, col6_3, col7_0 and col7_3.  Please let me know if I can provide any further information on the split. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple merge to accomplish this

```
df1_0 = df1[df1.col4==0].drop('col4',axis=1)
df1_3 = df1[df1.col4==3].drop('col4',axis=1)

result = pandas.merge( df1_0, df1_3, on=['col1','col2'],suffixes=['_0','_3']  )
result = result[sorted(list(result))] # to get columns in the order you like

   col1  col2  col3_0  col3_3  col5      col6_0      col6_3      col7_0  \
0     2     1    2000    2000   233  251.109065  251.109065   18.858343   
1     2     2    2000    5000    96  300.141548  412.916402   67.874851   
2     2     3    2000    5000    53  291.836682  394.260558   58.692756   
3     2     4    2000    5000    29  327.351227  478.924355   95.252774   
4     2     5    2000    5000    24  371.598847  574.811102  136.983014   

       col7_3  
0   18.858343  
1 -127.405555  
2 -148.001670  
3  -63.949017  
4   26.888185
```

Answer (score 0):

```
res = pd.merge(df1[df1.col4 == 0].drop('col4', axis=1), df1[df1.col4 == 3].drop('col4', axis=1), on=['col1', 'col2', 'col5'], suffixes=['_0', '_3'])

   col1  col2  col3_0  col5    col6_0    col7_0  col3_3    col6_3    col7_3
0     2     1    2000   233  251.1091   18.8583    2000  251.1091   18.8583
1     2     2    2000    96  300.1415   67.8749    5000  412.9164 -127.4056
2     2     3    2000    53  291.8367   58.6928    5000  394.2606 -148.0017
3     2     4    2000    29  327.3512   95.2528    5000  478.9244  -63.9490
4     2     5    2000    24  371.5988  136.9830    5000  574.8111   26.8882

# to sort columns
res.T.sort_index().T

   col1  col2  col3_0  col3_3  col5    col6_0    col6_3    col7_0    col7_3
0     2     1    2000    2000   233  251.1091  251.1091   18.8583   18.8583
1     2     2    2000    5000    96  300.1415  412.9164   67.8749 -127.4056
2     2     3    2000    5000    53  291.8367  394.2606   58.6928 -148.0017
3     2     4    2000    5000    29  327.3512  478.9244   95.2528  -63.9490
4     2     5    2000    5000    24  371.5988  574.8111  136.9830   26.8882
```